# Pass by Reference in Callbacks

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, objective-c-blocks, pass-by-reference

I am facing a problem. I am passing an object to another class by its reference & setting the value in that object. Now when I access this variable in callback handler then It is nil.

My sample code is:

**Class A:**

```
__block NSString *getListJobId = nil;
ClassB *bobject = [[ClassB alloc]init];
    [bobject getItemsWithJobId:&getListJobId onSuccess:^(NSArray *response) {
        NSLog(@"job id %@",getListJobId); //It is nil, It should be **shiv**
    } onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
    }];
```

**Class B:**
***.h***

```
- (void)getItemsWithJobId:(NSString **)jobId onSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *))completedBlock onFailure:(void (^)(NSError *))failureBlock;
```

***.m***

```
- (void)getItemsWithJobId:(NSString **)jobId onSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *))completedBlock onFailure:(void (^)(NSError *))failureBlock
{
    *jobId = @"shiv";
    completedBlock([NSArray new]);
}
```

I am getting this **jobId** **nil** in class A in callback response. How can I get this value from class B to class A.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Try initializing `getListJobId ` to NULL instead of nil

Comment: @gabuh: Its not working.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass by reference to get an updated value in the method, because the `getListJobId` at ClassA and ClassB do not point same address.

An Obj-C block capture the value of variables outside of its enclosing scope.
See "Blocks Can Capture Values from the Enclosing Scope" section.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Instead of passing by reference, we can get the updated value from arguments of the block and update `getListJobId` in the block.

**Class A:**

```
__block NSString *getListJobId = nil;
ClassB *bobject = [[ClassB alloc] init];
[bobject getItemsWithJobId:getListJobId onSuccess:^(NSArray *response, NSString *updatedJobId) {
    getListJobId = updatedJobId;
    NSLog(@"job id %@", getListJobId); // job id **shiv**
} onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
}];
```

**Class B: .h**

```
- (void)getItemsWithJobId:(NSString *)jobId onSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSString *))completedBlock onFailure:(void (^)(NSError *))failureBlock;
```

**.m**

```
- (void)getItemsWithJobId:(NSString *)jobId onSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSString *))completedBlock onFailure:(void (^)(NSError *))failureBlock
{
    NSString *updatedJobId = @"**shiv**";
    completedBlock([NSArray new], updatedJobId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Taking the address of a `__block` variable does not always do what you expect.**

In the current implementation, `__block` variables are initially allocated on the stack, and then "moved" to the heap upon any of the blocks that use it being moved to the heap (which is caused by the block being copied).

Therefore, *the address of a `__block` variable changes over its lifetime*. If you take the address of it, and it moves, then you will no longer be pointing to the version of the variable that everyone else is using.

Here, what is happening is that you take the address of the `__block` variable `getListJobId` while it is still on the stack. It is still on the stack at that point because it is caused to be moved to the heap by the copying of any block that uses it, but no block has been created at the point yet.

Then, a block that uses `getListJobId` gets copied somewhere and `getListJobId` gets moved to the heap. Exactly where this happens is not very clear, because ARC is allowed to insert copies of blocks in various places. Plus, the code you are showing here does not seem like your real code, because there would be no point to calling a "completion block" at the end of a method synchronously (in that case you would just return and let the caller perform the operations they want when completed). Rather, your real code probably performs an asynchronous operation, at the end of which the completion handler is called. `dispatch_async` and related asynchronous functions copy the blocks passed to them (which in turn copy any blocks captured, and so on).

I am guessing that in your real code, both the `*jobId = @"shiv";` line and the calling of the completion block happen in the asynchronous operation. What is happening is that the creation of the asynchronous operation copies the block and causes `getListJobId` to be moved to the heap. So inside the asynchronous operation, `getListJobId` refers to the heap version of the variable. However, the `*jobId = @"shiv";` writes to the stack version of the variable, because `jobId` is a pointer taken from the address of the variable when it was still on the stack. So you are writing to and reading from different variables.

Furthermore, what you are doing in `*jobId = @"shiv";` is very dangerous, because by the time of the asynchronous operation, the stack frame of the original function call no longer exists. And writing to a variable on the stack after the stack frame is gone is undefined behavior, and you may be overwriting other unknown variables in memory. You are lucky it didn't crash.